# Retrieve data from two table using id

Tags: mysql

**Table1**

```
Id, name, addresses 
101,raja ,chennai
```

**Table2**

```
Id,group,name
101,a,siva
102,b,selva
```

I want retrieve data from two tables like
Table2.group=a and two table Id must equal then take address from table1 display
Id, name, Address, group

Comment: Have you heard about `JOIN`?

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far? Have you taken a look at some of the resources [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/)?

Since this is the type of pretty straightforward SQL query you're likely to do many times over, it's worth you reading the tutorials and learning it yourself. I'll give you a few pointers to begin:

1. Your two tables are connected by the `Id` field (most likely, this is the **primary key** for one table and the **foreign key** for another). You'll need to `JOIN` these two tables using that field.
2. You'll need to specify a `WHERE` clause to filter for your condition that `Table2.group = a`.
3. The fields you want to display can all be specified using `SELECT`. If you are selecting data `FROM` Table 1 and joining to Table 2, you won't need to specify the table name before the field name.

Comment: I am beginner and try query not work. Some query helpfull

Comment: @KavinSenthil what error are you getting in your query? Can you post your query as an edit to your question?